# How to check if WHERE = value does not exist and make it zero by default?

Tags: sql-server

My goal is to check if lineId's value exists. If not, it has to be zero by default.
Here is my datas:

[image]

For example:

SELECT lineId from table_name WHERE lineId = 80

There is no lineId = 80, then I want to see that lineId = 0 records.

Thanks, sincerely :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another method:

```
SELECT lineId 
FROM table_name 
WHERE lineId = 80

UNION ALL

SELECT lineId 
FROM table_name 
WHERE lineId = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1 
        FROM table_name 
        WHERE lineId = 80
      ) ;
```

And similar with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT lineId 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE lineId = 80
  )

SELECT * 
FROM cte

UNION ALL

SELECT lineId 
FROM table_name 
WHERE lineId = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cte
      ) ;
```

Comment: No sorts, but requires three lookups on the table

Answer (score 3):

This answer **does not require a sort**, and uses no joins.

- `UNION ALL` the two queries together.
- Add an ordering column to the union.
- `ORDER BY` that ordering
- Take the top 1 but including ties, so all of the first query or all of the second.

This does not use a sort because the compiler recognizes that the queries are sorted already and uses `Merge Concatenation` instead.

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  lineId
FROM (
    SELECT lineId, 1 AS ordering
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE lineId = 80

    UNION ALL

    SELECT lineId, 2
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE lineId = 0
) t
ORDER BY ordering;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/4pHhOZDS)

[PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hke4NKHxs)

---

Another option is to begin with a dummy row from a `VALUES` table, then left-join the first half of the query. Then, within an `APPLY`, do the same thing with the other half.

```sql
SELECT 
    lineId = ISNULL(FirstHalf.lineId, SecondHalf.lineId)
FROM (VALUES(1)) v(dummy)
LEFT JOIN dbo.table_name AS FirstHalf ON FirstHalf.lineId = @ToFind
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TN.lineId 
    FROM (VALUES(1)) v2(dummy)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.table_name AS TN ON 
        TN.lineId = 0
        AND FirstHalf.lineId IS NULL
) AS SecondHalf
WHERE ISNULL(FirstHalf.lineId, SecondHalf.lineId) IS NOT NULL;
```

Or slightly differently

```sql
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (1000000000) TN.lineId 
    FROM dbo.table_name AS TN WHERE
        TN.lineId = 0
        AND FirstHalf.lineId IS NULL
) AS SecondHalf;
```

The benefit of this version is that **it does not query the second half at all**, whereas my other option will pull at least one row from both halves due to the Merge.

You need to very carefully read the execution plan to ensure this happens: it need a `Filter` with a startup predicate on the lower side of the main join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the desired output.

```
 WITH cte AS 
(
           SELECT *, 
                  dense_rank() OVER ( ORDER BY CASE  WHEN lineId= 80 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ) rn
           FROM table_name
           WHERE lineId IN (80,0)
) SELECT lineId 
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

All the steps can be found in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mvcSyC-O)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it could be 120, 123, 10 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Create an always-true condition on one of the columns such as the Clustered key or 1=1 condition, Then you can see the result by creating a case command on your LineId. A query like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN LineId<>80  THEN LineId ELSE 2 END 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: `WHERE 1=1` doesn't change the logic in this query, and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to join the table with itself, but you need one further unique column (like `id`, or `customer_no`, ...etc.) :

```sql
select 

case when not exists (select C.lineId from **table_name C** where B.id= C.id) 
  THEN 0 
  ELSE B.lineId END as lineId 

from **table_name B** 
group by 1 ;
```